# Merge /var partition with /

Tags: partitioning, gparted

So, I did a stupid mistake and allocated 8GB for my `/var` partition because I thought that would be sufficient, but now I am running out of space in my `/var` partition and I just want to merge it with my `/` partition which contains 48GB, but I don't know how to do so with already partitions spaces.

I tried looking around for ways to safely do that without having to start with a fresh install but it seems most solutions either start a new installation or assume that I am allocating more space from free space.

Is there a way to go about doing so using gparted or maybe some other tool?

[Here is a picture of Gparted with all details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVCGH.png)

Comment: How many partitions did you create? How many do you need to merge?

Comment: @user535733 I have 4 partitions if you don't count the Swap (logical partition). Besides the two I mentioned, I also have a `/boot` and a `/home` partition. All `ext4`.